# custom amount subtraction from more than one cell in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(".submitNum").click(function() {

  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var $remaining = $tr.find(".remaining");
  var $qty = $tr.find(".stockQuantity");
  var $numToSubmit = $tr.find(".customInput");

  //Get current values
  var batchSize = $remaining.attr("data-maxNumber");
  var currentRemaining = $remaining.text();
  var currentQty = $qty.text();
  var currentInputValue = $numToSubmit.val();
  var difference = Number(currentRemaining) - Number(currentInputValue);
  var divisible = Number(currentInputValue) / Number(batchSize);
  var usesFromQuantity = Number(currentQty) * Number(batchSize);
  var totalUses = Number(usesFromQuantity) + Number(currentRemaining);
  var decimalPart = divisible - Math.round(divisible);
  var finalRemaining = Number(decimalPart) * Number(batchSize);
  //Subtract values

  if (currentInputValue < 0) {
    alert('Please insert a valid quantity to withdraw');
  } else if (currentInputValue > totalUses) {
    alert("Cannot withdraw this amount");
  } else if (currentInputValue > Number(batchSize) + Number(currentRemaining) &&
    Number(currentInputValue) < Number(totalUses)) {
    currentQty = Number(currentQty) - Math.round(divisible);
    currentRemaining = Math.round(finalRemaining);

  } else if (difference == 0) {
    currentRemaining = batchSize;
    currentQty = currentQty - 1;
  } else if (difference < 0) {
    currentRemaining = Number(difference) + Number(batchSize);
    currentQty = Number(currentQty) - 1;
  } else if (difference > 0) {
    currentRemaining = difference;
  } else if (currentInputValue == totalUses) {
    currentRemaining = 0;
    currentQty = 0;
  }
  //Update text
  $remaining.text(currentRemaining);
  $qty.text(currentQty);

  $tr.find(".collapseX").hide();
  $tr.find(".inputBtn").show();
  $tr.find('.customInput').val('');

});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Stock Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Remaining Uses</th>
      <th scope="col">Withdraw Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>#Item1</td>
      <td class="stockQuantity">3</td>
      <td data-maxNumber="30" class="remaining">15</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li class="list-inline-item">
            <input placeholder="Set uses qty" class="customInput" type="number" min="1">
          </li>

          <li class="list-inline-item"><button href="#" class=" submitNum">Sumit</button></li>

        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Okay so:

1. 1 unit of `stock quantity` has 30 x `remaining uses`
2. What I am confused in is creating an algorithm that calculates how much is left in the `stock quantity` and the `remaining uses` if the value of the input field is an amount that exceeds the current `remaining uses` + `30` which is the amount per 1 unit of `stock quantity`so I can know how many units should I withdraw from `stock quantity` and how many units should be remaining in `remaining uses`.
3. The jquery function I have here is a bit big and cluttered, but its functional when I want to withdraw an amount that is less than or equal `remaining uses + 30`.
4. of course there can be smarter ways to do this feel free to change the whole thing
5. to understand what I mean better try withdrawing `(45 units)` or less it'll work and then try to withdraw `(70 units)` here you'll notice the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator (%) to quickly figure out how many come out of remaining.

Say you have:

```
var qty = 3;
var remaining = 20;
var batchSize = 30;
var withdrawAttempt = 45;
```

Then:

```
var totalLeft = remaining + batchSize * qty;

if (withdrawAttempt > totalLeft) {
  // invalid
} else {
  // calculate how many to take from remaining
  var wr = withdrawAttempt % batchSize;
  // update qty and remaining
  qty -= (withdrawAttempt - wr) / batchSize;
  remaining -= wr;
  if (remaining < 0) {
    remaining += batchSize;
    qty -= 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works mainly, but if you with withdraw 45 two times in a row, `remaining` = `-10.`